# how to notify mouseplacing on a widget is with a color

Tags: qt4

hai
 i just want to change the color of the buttons when i move the mouse on it....ie if i place mouse on pushbutton1 i want to chenge its color to green...when i remove the mouse from it i wants the old color....how can i achieve this.....i have many buttons and other widget in my mainwindow....i want for every widget like dis....

thanks in advance

Comment: If Arnold's answer has solved your problem, you should accept it (by clicking on the big tick mark). This shows your gratitude and gives Arnold some reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by setting the style sheet of the button.

```
MyButton.setStyleSheet("*:hover {background: green }");
```

This will control the color just for the button you apply it to.

If you want all the buttons on a form to have the same behaviour, set the style sheet of the widget containing the buttons instead.

```
MyWidget.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover {background: green }");
```

Style sheets are a very powerful option for customizing the look of your application. You can find more information [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/stylesheet.html).